# How to save a file in a Firestore database from a multipart/formData request?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a firebase function :

```js
//Functions and firestore requirements are here

exports.saveData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Data received")
  const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
  const fields = {}
  const uploads = {}

  //Push fields that are not file in fields
  busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    console.log(`Processed field ${fieldname}: ${val}.`);
    fields[fieldname] = val;
  });
  //Push files in uploads
  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
    console.log('File :', file);
    const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
    uploads[fieldname] = filepath;
  });
  busboy.on('finish', () => { 
    console.log(uploads)
    console.log(fields)
    db.collection("a_collection").add({
        a: fields.a,
        b: fields.b,
        file: "Help ! From the client, I send an image. Which value do I need to save ?"
    })
    .then(function () {
        res.send("Data is saved")
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
        console.error("Error :" + error)
    })
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
  

})
```

I want to save image and data from multipart/formData requests in a Firestore database. How can I do this ? Do I need to save a base64 image or there is an other way to save files in google cloud firestore ?

My english is not perfect, Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to save it as Base64 test so that you can upload it to Firestore.

So what you can do is read your file transform it to Base64 and then add it to your Firestore database.

To get the Base 64 you can use this

```
//Get Base64 of file
function getBase64(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
       console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        let encoded = reader.result.split(',');
        //you split this to get mimetype out of your base64
        addForSale(Date.now().toString(10), { uFile: encoded[1]});
        // I just used a timestamp as the ID
    }
};
```

The other alternative is to upload the files to Cloud Storage and save in Firestore the location of the file in Cloud Storage.