# how to add image in firestore by manually in cloud firestore collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have tired to add image to firestore of my e-commerce app product detail. But it does not has any datatype about image .
so how can I add image into firestore

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154144/how-to-save-a-file-in-a-firestore-database-from-a-multipart-formdata-request

Comment: here I already answered it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154144/how-to-save-a-file-in-a-firestore-database-from-a-multipart-formdata-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a file in a Firestore database from a multipart/formData request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154144/how-to-save-a-file-in-a-firestore-database-from-a-multipart-formdata-request)

Answer (score 0):

For uploading images you will have to use `CloudStorage`. You can find it here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage&ved=2ahUKEwiixLvgwpzvAhXGpIsKHYWpDl4QFnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw262xR8v-7_N9qJrmI4UEw3